Is there anybody facing the issue that selecting some contents in TinyMCE, and clicking TinyMCE area, then selected contents was remoted
Is there anybody facing the issue:
When selecting some contents in TinyMCE, and clicking other TinyMCE area, then selected contents disappeared - was remoted by tool.
The issue happened occasionally.
Please help to find out the root cause or any possibility.
